# Pytorch VGG16 throwing a matrix multiplication RuntimeError during inference

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, vgg-net

I'm trying to extract VGG16 features of images as part of a project. However, at the time of extracting the features, I am met with an `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (512x49 and 25088x4096)`. The error is triggered at line 69 of `vgg.py`, at the `x = self.classifier(x)` instruction.

The simplest bit of code that I have found to reproduce the bug is the following:

```
import torchvision, torch
feature_extractor = torchvision.models.vgg16()
im_size = 224
a = torch.rand([3, im_size, im_size])
feature_extractor(a)
```

I don't think that the problem is the shape of the input tensor, since the error is raised pretty late in the `forward` function of VGG16. I can't think of a way to solve this. Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the error appears sai late nor why the documentation doesn’t cover it, but the problem is indeed the tensor shape. The model expects one more index before all the other representing the mini batch. Therefore, the following code does not throw an error:

```
import torchvision, torch
feature_extractor = torchvision.models.vgg16()
im_size = 224
a = torch.rand([1, 3, im_size, im_size])
feature_extractor(a)
```

If you want to apply the model to a single image, use unsqueeze to apply an extra leading dimension:

```
a = torch.rand([3, im_size, im_size])
a = torch.unsqueeze(a,0)
feature_extractor(a)
```